# cbind each row from one data to another in R

Tags: r, cbind

My dataset looks like this:

```
df1<-t(data.frame(1,2,3))
df2<-t(data.frame(4,5,6))
colnames(df1)<-c('A')
colnames(df2)<-c('B')
> df1
   A
X1 1
X2 2
X3 3
> df2
   B
X4 4
X5 5
X6 6
```

How can I merge each row in df1 to df2 so that I have something like this:

```
A  B  
1  4
1  5
1  6
2  4
2  5
2  6
3  4
3  5
3  6
```

Thanks!!

Comment: Small side note: creating your example data frames would be much simpler as `data.frame(A = 1:3)` and `data.frame(B = 4:6)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is likely to be a duplicate. Here are three similar solutions:

- `merge(df1, df2)`
- `expand.grid(A = df1, B = df2)`
- `tidyr::crossing(A = df1, B = df2)`

Comment: I didn't realize that I can do that by a simple `merge` command. Thanks!!

Answer (score 4):

You can use `expand.grid`:

```
expand.grid(A = df1, B = df2)
  A B
1 1 4
2 2 4
3 3 4
4 1 5
5 2 5
6 3 5
7 1 6
8 2 6
9 3 6
```